# Support of density

Tags: probability-theory

How do you determine the support of the sum of two random variables?

For example, if X,Y are independent random variables where Z=X+Y.
Im asked to find the density of Z, I use the convolution formula. But Im not sure on how you determine the support of $f_Z(z)$ after obtaining $f_Z(z)$.

Lets say that the support of X and Y is: $R_X=[a,b]$ and $R_Y=[A,B]$. What is $R_Z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
f_Z(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}f_X(s)f_Y(t-s)\,ds = \int_a^bf_X(s)f_Y(t-s)\,ds.
$$
Now, $t$ is not in the support of $f_Z$ if $f_Y(t-s) = 0$ for all $s\in [a,b]$, right? This is the case if $t-s\notin [A,B]$ for all $s\in [a,b]$. That is, $t\notin [A+s,B+s]$ for all $s\in [a,b]$. And this holds if $t\notin [A+a,B+b]$. So, if $t\notin [A+a,B+b]$, then $f_Y(t-s) = 0$ for all $s\in [a,b]$ and thus $f_Z(t) = 0$. This implies that the support of $f_Z$ is contained in $[A+a,B+b]$.

Comment: Ah okay nice, that makes sense ;]

By the way, when carrying out the calculations in the integral. Am I doing it right when using the indicator function for $f_Y(t-s)$, and then obtaining the limits for $f_Y(t-s)$ and combining this with the integral limits?

Comment: I don't understand that. I can only say that you cannot replace $f_Y$ by an indicator function. Why should this be possible?

Comment: Think I phrased it wrong. But denote it as $(f_Y1_{\{t-s \in [A,B] \}})$, and then obtaining an inequality for $t-s$. Then obtain the values for s in that inequality, and combine it with the limits of the integral?

Comment: What we will have is that $ t-B \leq s \leq t-A$, and since we are integrating over [a,b] the ingration limits becomes: $\int_{max(a,t-b)}^{min(b,t-A)} $ ?

Comment: @fejz1234 "denote it as" Denote _what_ as? I cannot follow you.

Comment: The support of $f_Y(t-s)$ can be expressed with an indicator multiplied with $f_Y$? Or am I phrasing it completly wrong?

Comment: @fejz1234 I think you are thinking it much too complicated. If $t\notin [A+a,B+b]$, then $f_Y(t-s) = 0$ for all $s\in [a,b]$. Hence, the integrand in $f_Z(t)$ is zero. Thus, $f_Z(t) = 0$.

Comment: Okay, so I shouldnt set up the integral as this: $\int_a^b f_X(s)f_Y(t-s) ds= \int_a^b f_X(s)(f_Y(t-s)1_{\{t-B\leq s \leq t-A\}}) ds = \int_{max(a,t-B)}^{min(b,t-A)} f_X(s)f_Y(t-s) ds$  ?

Comment: You can do that. And then?

Comment: The problem for me was that I didn't know the support of Z, with the support  known $R_Z=[A+a,B+b]$ I should be able to determine the limits of the integral. Or how do you carry out the calculations for the integral? Is this the standard way?

Comment: @fejz1234 What do you mean by "Or how do you carry out the calculations for the integral?" You asked for the support of $f_Z$. Now, you know that it is contained in $[A+a,B+b]$. What you do there with max and min is fine. But for this, you don't need the support of $f_Z$.

Comment: But how do I determine $max(a,t-B)$ and $min(b,t-A)$ without the support of $f_Z$ ?

Comment: I meant if there is an easier way to calculate the integral, than the way that I set it up. Am I doing it too complicated, or is this the usual method that one does when calculating the integral of the convolution?

Comment: You cannot use the support of $f_Z$ to simplify this.

Comment: Think I am a bit confused now, what are the values of $t$ then? Isn't $t$ the values in the support of $f_Z$ ?

Comment: Why? Of course you can pick $t$ outside the support. Then the integral is zero.

Comment: Ok, Im not sure if I get this. How do you simplify $max(a,t-B)$ and $min(b,t-A)$ without the support?

Comment: I mean sure I can simplify it if I let $t\in \mathbb{R}$. But how can I know that the obtained limits $c_1=max(a,t-B)$ and $c_2=min(b,t-A)$ is in the support of $f_Z$? If not, then Im integrating zero without being aware of it?

Comment: You mix something here. The min/max limits are limits for $s$. The support of $f_Z$ is about $t$.

Comment: You can also proceed as follows: Instead of the min/max limits, you can integrate over the intersection $[a,b]\cap [t-B,t-A]$. This intersection is non-empty iff $t-B < b$ and $t-A > a$, that is, $t < B+b$ and $t > A+a$.

Comment: Ok so, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(s)f_Y(t-s)ds=\int_{A+a}^{B+b} f_X(s)f_Y(t-s) ds$ ?

Comment: No. I don't like to repeat myself. Read my comments. I wrote "You mix something here". Last time: You don't integrate over $t$ ,but over $s$!

Comment: Okay, I thought you said that I could integrate over the intersection of $[a,b]$ and $[t-B,t-A]$ instead, which was $t\in[A+a,B+b]$ ?

Comment: Ok. If you don't read and take into account what I write, I give up.